# .net method attributes

Tags: .net

I need to call some code before calling methods that decorated by Attribute [MyTracedMethod] and after.

Can i do this by .net Method Atributes?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Can you please provide more explanation?

Comment: I develop "soft remote reboot" for my app.Some critical app method may marked bye attribute.[CriticalForReboot] for example.

Comment: There methods "block" reboot until they processing something

Answer (score 2):

You will need an [AOP Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) for this, like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).

See '[getting started](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation/getting-started)' for a simple example.